# How to make an ajax call to a page and wait for the ajax calls on that page to finish

Tags: javascript, web

I am doing a simple ajax call.but in the page i'm calling there's an ajax call to a pdf file. Is there a way to make the page wait until all the ajax calls on the requested page are loaded? I am getting as well the following error :"Can't create DocumentThreadableLoader"

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "text",
    url: '/test/test.pdf',
    success: function (data) {
        $('body').html(data);
    },
    data: body
});
```

Comment: use callbacks in onSuccess event

Answer (score 0):

**Not recommended since ajax is meant for async calls**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "text",
    async: false, // ADD THIS LINE
    url: '/test/test.pdf',
    success: function (data) {
        $('body').html(data);
    },
    data: body
});
```

**Best Solution**

Use callback structure and or jQuery built in promises (success, done, always, complete, etc).

**load pdf data into html body**

`$( "body" ).load( "test/test.pdf" );`

Comment: By doing this i can still see the ajax calls of the requested page on the current page. any other ideas?

Comment: That is what should happen since you are passing the `data` argument into the html body in the success function.  Explain again what you are trying to do?  You are trying to load PDF data into the body is that right?

Comment: I updated the code to load the pdf data to the body lmk how that goes.

Comment: Basically what i'm trying to do is to call a page that have ajax calls and show the user the content without letting him know which links i'm using to generate the data in the page.

Comment: then you should be using URI's and not URL's.  Check out REST

Comment: Yes you are correct but any ideas on how it can be done , i'm honestly out of ideas